# Pygame flickering

Tags: python, pygame

Pygame keeps flickering, even though it calls `pygame.display.update` once.

I believe the problem is on `screen.fill` (src.py, function `clear`), but it doesn't work without it.

EDIT:

the complete code: find at http://mindgamestore.tk/pygame_code/

Comment: This code is missing some things - where is screen defined? What's inside it? Is it double buffered?

Comment: Likely unrelated, but I believe you are shadowing the definition of pygame's `Sprite` in `src.py`.

Comment: @monkey I use my own `Sprite` module wo/ problems. Pygame's modules is too confuse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved the problem: `pygame.display.flip` was being called more than once on `idraw` function.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that pygame needs to clear the screen before doing anything.

So: in your while loop, before drawing anything on the screen, fill the screen with a color.

```
screen.fill([255,255,255])
```

If you have an back ground image, simply draw it after the above code .

Answer (score 1):

Reviving this to give an alternative solution.

So, at last, if nothing works, it is possible to simple remove `pygame.HWSURFACE` and `pygame.DOUBLEBUF` from `pygame.display.set_mode`. This worked very well for me.

Comment: Explaining, some systems aren't capable to process certain amount of data per second/milissecond, due to their limited processors (like PMP's). So, to use pygame.HWSURFACE, may require more than these poor hardware offers.